# Bad makes you better?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for when a person does a job so poorly that you go out of your way to do your job better?

All I can come up with is reverse inspiration, but I can imagine some long German word that would combine these together in an awesome way.

Edit: Note that the job is not necessarily the same, so the term 'covering' does not really answer the question.  The objective is not external recognition, such that 'outshine' is a consequence of doing a better job rather than the objective.

Edit 2: The question does not stem from someone making mistakes so much as being highly unmotivated to do the job well.  A poor choice of words initially it would seem.  To rephrase the question:

"Is there a term for when a person is so lazy at doing their job that you go out of your way to do your job better?"

The accepted answer 'compensate' effectively addresses this question.

Comment: What about outshine?

Comment: Are you asking about learning from someone else's (or your) mistakes and then, feeling an ambition to make things better? If you clarify further, I will re-open. It is still not clear.

Comment: Do these things stay on hold forever?  Can it be put to rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word 'compensate' encapsulates this meaning. For example: "Because Anita was so terrible at making tacos, I had to compensate for her incompetence by making twice as many."

Comment: Well stated.  Now the trick is to get the person financially compensated for compensating.

Comment: How come this answers the question? This is covering for someone. This is not doing your job better. Isn't the question about learning lessons from mistakes or failure?

Comment: @ermanen The way the question was phrased does not make it seem like it was about learning from someone else's failure as much as having to 'go out of your way' on account of someone else's inability to do their job. I can't think of a single word for learning from someone else's mistakes but am now very curious as to if there is one.